# Clear data does not remove getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android

Clear data option from application settings does not remove data from sd card located in getExternalStorageDirectory() 
It does compute it size but does not clear!

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show what are you doing at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear Data only removes the data you have stored inside your applications private space. If you are saving to the SD Card, then you will have to delete from the SD Card yourself. Please check the Android Documentation on the Applications Storage and your options.

Comment: And how to catch event when user clears data?
But android can delete this folder when uninstalling app, why it can't wipe it?

Comment: You cannot get an event when the user clears the internal data as this is not handled by your application, but only by the OS. The storage is internal, and therefore it is not related to the SD Card. Please read the Android Documentation on the storage options, as it will explain your options.

Comment: Well, what do you mean "The storage is internal, and therefore it is not related to the SD Card" - getExternalStorageDirectory() is storage for application on sd card. It is special formatted path, so android OS can associate it with application (please read documentation).
So if android can remove this folder on application uninstall, why it can't wipe it on "Clear Data"?
I think this is some kind of bug in android :(

Comment: The device has two main storage locations. One is classed as internal, which is private, and the other is external, which is accessible to any app and via your PC etc. If you check the docs, you will see that this is NOT associated with your app. If you created a folder on the SD card, I would be able to write an application which could search for your folder, and delete it. Clear Data is associated with the internal/private storage of the device. Again, please read the docs properly http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 2):

Clear() is only for sharredPreference.

Use this method to remove a file in a directory: [deleteFile()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: This is a valid answer, my comments above are just an explanation.